# Writing a double-jump (no table) in Lazarus (Free Pascal) ASM

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, freepascal, lazarus

I'm writing for Intel X64. RAX holds a value between 0 and 15. I want execution to jump to the corresponding labels, which are illustrated.

```
  lea           r11, [rip+@@table]
  shl           rax, 1     // multiply by 2 for offset
  add           r11, rax
  jmp           r11        // jmp into the table below then jmp again

@@table:
  jmp           @@0
  jmp           @@1
  jmp           @@2
  jmp           @@3
  jmp           @@4
  jmp           @@5
  jmp           @@6
  jmp           @@7
  jmp           @@8
  jmp           @@9
  jmp           @@10
  jmp           @@11
  jmp           @@12
  jmp           @@13
  jmp           @@14
  jmp           @@15

@@0:
  mov           eax, 100
  jmp @@ret

@@1:
  mov           eax, -10
  jmp @@ret                                         
...
```

This works fine if RAX is 0. If the -10 at @@1 is changed to 10, it works there too. This means the compiler is illiminating the entire @@table: jmp sequence.

I've turned off optimizations, but that didn't help. Clearly I'm not doing this the correct way.

How do I stop the compiler from optimizing out the jmp's. Or, alternately, is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure the compiler generated a 2 byte jmp? I doubt it has eliminated the jumps, check in a disassembler. Chances are you got a 5 byte near jmp, so maybe try `lea r11, [r11 + rax + 4*rax]` instead of the `shl+add`

Comment: I'm certain it has eliminated them because the size of the jumps needs to vary depending on the width of the value I load within the labels. So if I manually jmp 2, I know it's going directly to @@1.

Comment: I don't understand this comment at all.

Comment: If I manually set RAX to 0, 1, 2, 3 etc, and all the mov eax, 100 etc. commands have a *1* byte number, it all works, If I specify say -10 (requiring 4 bytes), it no longer works. This proves that the jmp table is being eliminated and that the initial jmp starts at @@0 instead of @@table

Comment: There is no `mov r32, imm8` the `mov eax, 100` is 5 bytes just as `mov eax, -10`. Changing the constant can't make a difference here. I still say check the actual disassembly.